# Is Sun PKCS#11 provider supported on Android?

Tags: java, android, security, pkcs#11

Is Sun PKCS#11 provider supported on Android? Or can it be moved to Android somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Sun==Oracle => copying bad :)

Seriously though, it is not available in Android and there is not standard PKCS#11 support either (although JB does use a proprietary PKCS#11 provider for some things). Not sure if the code is in OpenJDK, but if it is, you can try to port it. However, since it is unlikely that you actually need to use the full PKCS#11 API, it will be much easier to write JNI wrappers only for the functions you need (sighing, verifying, hashing, etc.).