# Signing data using PKCS11 library in an Android application

Tags: java, android, pkcs#11

I am new to android development and would like to understand if its possible to sign data using smart card token through android application.
Is ther any way to use PKCS#11 library statically with an android application?
How can this be achieved?

I tried including SunPKCS#11 imports into the android java class but may missing some steps.

```
    try {
        // Load the Sun PKCS#11 provider dynamically
        String configName = "/path/to/pkcs11/config.cfg"; // Path to your PKCS#11 config file
        Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
        //Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11
        Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

        // Initialize PKCS#11 KeyStore
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        char[] pin = "YOUR_PIN".toCharArray();
        keyStore.load(null, pin);

        // List certificates
        Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();
            Log.d("pkcs","Certificate Alias: " + alias);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how to set up config.cfg

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Can you please include your attempt with the code you were using? Did you experience any error? If so, can you include it in your question? What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @dan1st please check the snippet.

Comment: How do you see that snippet isn't working? Which class isn't found? `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Sun PKCS#11 provider supported on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354137/is-sun-pkcs11-provider-supported-on-android) However, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/59cd43352e5fd4907303d06f9b92f01c943375f7/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/security/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.java seems to exist but it doesn't seem to extend `Provider`. Alternatively, you could try https://github.com/DDoSolitary/SunPKCS11Wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ddosolitary/pkcs11/SunPKCS11Wrapper.java from https://github.com/DDoSolitary/SunPKCS11Wrapper